# Hide mouse pointer / cursor when playing video / slideshow in Inno Setup

Tags: cursor, inno-setup

I created an Inno Setup script that plays a slideShow or a video during program installation depending on what I choose to play.

When I bring mouse to the area which the playback is doing during the slideshow / video playback, a cursor (`crArrow`) is appearing on video / slideshow.

I want to prevent the mouse cursor from being displayed on video / slideshow while the slideshow / video is playing.

When using `crNone` property for the handling form window (`BackgroundForm`) the cursor is hiding only from it and not from slideshow / video. Isn't there anyway I can hide the cursor from slideshow/video? How can I apply `crNone` for that? I mean like `SlideShow.crNone` or `Video.crNone`.

I attached two images showing how the cursor appearing.

- [The Cursor appearing when playing SlideShow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Jww.jpg)
- [The Cursor appearing when playing Video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwfzK.jpg)

---

How I handle video on the `BackgroundForm` using Inno Media Player:

```pascal
procedure PlayMPEGVideo();
begin
  if VBRadio2.Checked then begin
    if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Video.mp4')) then
    begin
      if DSInitializeVideoFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Video.mp4'), BackgroundForm.Handle, Width, Height, @BackgroundVideoPlay) then
      begin
        BackgroundForm.Width := GetSystemMetrics(0);
        BackgroundForm.Height := GetSystemMetrics(1);
        BASS_Pause;
        SoundCtrlButton.Enabled := False;
        DSSetVolume(-0);
        DSPlayMediaFile;
        WizardForm.BringToFront;
        PauseBT.Show;
        PlayBT1.hide;
        PlayBT.hide;
        with WizardForm do begin
          WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := 'Install';
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    with WizardForm do begin
      if CurPageID = wpInstalling then begin
        PauseBT.hide;
        CompactCheckBox.Visible := False;
        WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Show;
        WizardForm.Bevel1.Show;
        with WizardForm do begin
          WizardForm.ProgressGauge.show;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

How I handle slideshow on the `BackgroundForm` using isSlideShow:

```pascal
procedure MakeSlideShow();
var
  i :integer;
begin
  if NoBackgroundCheckBox.Checked = True then begin
    with WizardForm do begin
      if CurPageID=wpInstalling then begin
        PauseBT.hide;
        CompactCheckBox.Visible := False;
        WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Show;
        WizardForm.Bevel1.Show;
        with WizardForm do begin
          WizardForm.ProgressGauge.show;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    BackgroundForm:= TForm.Create(nil);
    BackgroundForm.BorderStyle:= bsNone;
    BackgroundForm.Color:=clBlack;
    BackgroundForm.SetBounds(0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1))
    BackgroundForm.Visible:=True;
    BackgroundForm.enabled:= False;
    PicList:=tstringlist.Create;
#ifexist "Slides\1.jpg"
#sub ExtractFile
    ExtractTemporaryFile('{#i}.jpg');
#endsub
#for {i = 1; FileExists(StringChange("Slides\FileName.jpg", "FileName", Str(i))) != 0; i++} ExtractFile
#endif
    i:=1;
    repeat
      piclist.add(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\'+IntToStr(i)+'.jpg'));
      i:=i+1;
    until FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\'+IntToStr(i)+'.jpg')) = False;
    BackgroundForm.Show;
    InitializeSlideShow(BackgroundForm.Handle, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1), true, 1);
    ShowImage(ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\1.jpg', 1);
    PlayBT1 := PlayBT;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general**, to hide a mouse cursor, set the `.Cursor` property of a control to `crNone`.

---

**For Inno Media Player**: There's no "video" control exposed by its API. You would have to modify its source code and recompile. Particularly, you need to call the [`IVideoWindow::HideCursor` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms786971(v=vs.85)) on the `FVideoWindow` in the `TDirectShowPlayer.InitializeVideoWindow`.

```pascal
const
  OATRUE = -1;

procedure TDirectShowPlayer.InitializeVideoWindow(WindowHandle: HWND; var Width,
  Height: Integer);
begin
  ErrorCheck(FGraphBuilder.QueryInterface(IVideoWindow, FVideoWindow));
  ErrorCheck(FVideoWindow.HideCursor(OATRUE));
  ...
end;
```

Note that it does not work, when the parent window (the `BackgroundForm`) is disabled. So you cannot set the `BackgroundForm.Enabled := False`.
To prevent the background/video window from getting activated, handle the `TForm.OnActive` by returning focus back to the wizard form:

```pascal
procedure BackgroundFormActivated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.BringToFront;
end;

...
begin
  ...
  BackgroundForm:= TForm.Create(nil);
  ...
  BackgroundForm.OnActivate := @BackgroundFormActivated;
end;
```

This is a complete code that works for me - hides the cursor over the background video - when using the recompiled `MediaPlayer.dll` with the `HideCursor` call, provided by you - tested on Windows 10.

```pascal
var
  BackgroundForm: TForm;

procedure OnMediaPlayerEvent(EventCode, Param1, Param2: Integer); 
begin
  { noop }
end;

procedure BackgroundFormActivated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.BringToFront;
end;

procedure PlayMPEGVideo();
var
  Width, Height: Integer;
begin
  BackgroundForm := TForm.Create(nil);
  BackgroundForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  BackgroundForm.Color := clBlack;
  BackgroundForm.Visible := True;
  BackgroundForm.Cursor := crNone;
  BackgroundForm.OnActivate := @BackgroundFormActivated;

  Width := GetSystemMetrics(0);
  Height := GetSystemMetrics(1);
  BackgroundForm.SetBounds(0, 0, Width, Height)

  if DSInitializeVideoFile(
       '...\video.avi', BackgroundForm.Handle, Width, Height, @OnMediaPlayerEvent) then
  begin
    DSPlayMediaFile;
    WizardForm.BringToFront;
  end;
end;
```

---

**For isSlideShow**: I didn't find any documentation or source code for this.